# Java cache and equality

Tags: java, caching, object, integer, equality

I've been reading over java caches for class and I'm not exactly sure why this code works.

```
Integer x = new Integer(2);
Integer y = new Integer(2);
assert x            != y;
assert x.intValue() == y.intValue();
++x;
assert x            != y;
assert x.intValue() != y.intValue();
++y;
assert x            == y;
assert x.intValue() == y.intValue();
```

I understand that initially x and y are not equal because they reference different objects, but why do they become equal after the ++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the increment, they are reboxed using `Integer.valueOf()`, and for small absolute values (between `-128` and `127` by default), that uses the cached instances.

Answer (score 4):

The keyword here is *integer caching*. `Integer` values under `128`<sup>*</sup> are cached, and `++` returns an interning `valueOf` result.

There are two fun experiments you can perform to understand how caching of `Integers` works:

- Replace `new Integer(2)` with `Integer.valueOf(2)`, and observe that `x==y` right away
- Replace `2` with `200`, and observe that `x++` and `y++` return *different* objects

---

<sup>*</sup> There is an option to control this: `java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=high_val`

Comment: The values are pooled, not interned.

Comment: @SteveKuo Thanks for the note, I confused this with string interning. This is now fixed.